# ElasticBeanstalk enable DropInvalidHeaderFields on application loadbalancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-application-load-balancer

I have an Elastic Beanstalk web application with an application loadbalancer. I would like to enable the setting DropInvalidHeaderFields on that loadbalancer through an ebextension config file, but for everything that I have found online I get an error like this:

```
Invalid option specification (Namespace: 'aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment:proxy:loadbalancer', OptionName: 'DropInvalidHeaderFields'): Unknown configuration setting.
```

These are currently what I have tried:

```
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment:proxy:routing:
    http_drop_invalid_header_fields_enabled: true
```

```
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment:proxy:loadbalancer:
    LoadBalancerHTTPPort: '80'
    LoadBalancerHTTPSPort: '443'
    DropInvalidHeaderFields: true
```

```
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment:proxy:staticfiles:
    /: static/
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment:proxy:targetgroup:
    TargetGroup: |
      {
        "Arn": "ARN",
        "Protocol": "HTTP",
        "Port": "80",
        "DropInvalidHeaderFields": true
      }
```

I want to have this persistent when I would rebuild my environment, or create a new one with the same configuration.

Anyone know a way to achieve this? Does not have to be ebextension file, any way to set this persistent is fine for me.

Comment: Can you try `routing.http.drop_invalid_header_fields.enabled`
routing.http.drop_invalid_header_fields.enabled - Indicates whether HTTP headers with invalid header fields are removed by the load balancer (true) or routed to targets (false). The default is false.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/APIReference/API_LoadBalancerAttribute.html

Comment: That is the setting I am trying to change. But what do you mean with can you try? Where and how would you want me to try this?